# Jquery UI and Bootstrap JS conflicting making Autocomplete stop working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am attempting to implement autocomplete functionality in a search form. All is working as expected, but only if I disable bootstrap JS.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

<!--HTML Here-->

<script>
    $( function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#accountInput" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    } );
</script>
```

I am using laravel, the app.js file is where the bootstrap is loaded. When I run the code in this way I get this:

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function`

The error goes away completely when I do not include bootstrap's JS, but I need it included for separate functionality on the site.

Answer (score 0):

I think order of adding your `js` files makes this problem. You can change this order to below and test again.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $( function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#accountInput" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    } );
</script>

<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```